# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. [FLASK]

Tags: python, flask, heroku, pip

## ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

When i try to push my flask app to `Heroku` the following error shows up in my terminal and the build fails.

I can't figure out what's wrong here is the full error:

```py
Counting objects: 6422, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5375/5375), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6422/6422), 18.81 MiB | 668.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6422 (delta 2146), reused 4421 (delta 868)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting bcrypt==3.2.0
remote:          Downloading bcrypt-3.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (63 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==1.1.2
remote:          Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
remote:          Downloading Flask-Bcrypt-0.7.1.tar.gz (5.1 kB)
remote:        Collecting flask-pwa==0.1.0
remote:          Downloading flask_pwa-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-Session==0.3.2
remote:          Downloading Flask_Session-0.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
remote:          Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        Collecting flask-template==0.4.4
remote:          Downloading flask_template-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
remote:          Downloading Flask-WhooshAlchemy-0.56.tar.gz (8.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.11.2
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz (14 kB)
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a2gejoxi/MarkupSafe/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a2gejoxi/MarkupSafe/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-hgdhn9un
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-a2gejoxi/MarkupSafe/
remote:            Complete output (5 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-a2gejoxi/MarkupSafe/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
remote:            ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to <app name>.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/<app name>.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/<app name>.git'
```

Here is my requirements.txt:

```py
bcrypt==3.2.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
flask-pwa==0.1.0
Flask-Session==0.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
flask-template==0.4.4
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.0
python-dotenv==0.15.0
razorpay==1.2.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
sqlparse==0.4.1
validate-email==1.3
virtualenv==15.1.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
Whoosh==2.7.4
```

Please help me  it's my first time deploying an app to production.
I am using `linux` with `with python3.6`.
**Thanks for any help**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Feature` feature was removed from `setuptools` at version [`v46.0.0`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#v4600). To fix your problem either you need to upgrade `MarkupSafe` to a later version or downgrade `setuptools` to version < `v46.0.0`.

Try the latest `MarkupSafe` 1.1.1.

Comment: pip install --upgrade setuptools==45  fixed it.

Comment: @hoper `< v46` as I've said.